# Adding Table styling in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I am creating a table dynamically in javascript. Also i am suing some css code to format the tables. However, my code is not picking up any formatting. Not even the simplest ones like adding a border around table. Here is my code :

```
function parseRequest_ls(response) {
    document.getElementById("files").innerHTML += "<table border='2'>";

    for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
        if(response.data[i].type == "folder" || response.data[i].type == "album") {
            document.getElementById("files").innerHTML += "<tr><td><b>+</b> <a href='#'>"+ response.data[i].name + "</a></td></tr>";
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("files").innerHTML += "</ul></table></div>";
}
```

CSS Code:

```
table, th, td {
    border: 2px solid;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #555;
}

caption {
    font-size: 150%;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 5px;
}

td, th {
    padding: 4px;
}
```

Comment: It's probably because your html isn't valid. You can't place a ul directly inside a table element. It must be in a td. More to the point where did the ul come from, you don't create the starting tag in that piece of script. Nor do you open the div tag you're closing.

Comment: Can you just use jQuery and make this a lot simpler?

Comment: Your HTML is most likely dismissed because you are adding it piece by piece and it's invalid until the last piece. And as JLevett says, your HTML is deeply broken. You have stray closing tags all over the place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your function you have

```
document.getElementById("files").innerHTML += "<table border='2'>"; // first line
```

and

```
document.getElementById("files").innerHTML += "</ul></table></div>"; // last line
```

You have placed a closing ul tag `</ul>` and a closing div tag `</div>` at the last line but didn't use any starting `tag` for either `ul` and `div` so the `HTML` is broken and I think you should not use an `ul` inside a `table` without wrapping it inside a `td`. So in this case you can use

```
function parseRequest_ls(response) {
    var trs='';    
    for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
        if(response.data[i].type == "folder" || response.data[i].type == "album") {
            trs +="<tr><td><b>+</b> <a href='#'>"+ response.data[i].name + "</a></td></tr>";
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("files").innerHTML += "<table border='2'>"+trs+"</table>";
}
```

[**A simple example**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/Mq3cu/).

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `+=` with `innerHTML`. First build a string in a temporary variable, and then once you have some complete (and valid) HTML in your string, you can use `+=` to append it to an element.

Answer (score -1):

So the issue was, i can not create table via innerHTML. I had to do it using DOM Object. I created a DOM object and then, createElement to get the table. a bit not straight forward.. but it worked.. thanks all for your suggestions though. :)